# kill users processes in linux with php

Tags: php, apache2, exec, kill

I am trying to write a php script to kill users in a redhat machine.

I know it is possible (and very insecure) to give apache the ability to do things as root, but I need to be able to kill any user from a web page, does anyone have any good working scripts or point me to a place to find some more info?  I can use this code (which I took from php.net) to make it work, but I assume that this will work only if I give apache root permission or run apache as root.

```
<?php
    exec("kill -9 $pid");
?>
```

This command pulls the user and their process id which I assume once the apache issue is figured out will work just fine for grabbing the list of users for me to output.

```
who -u | awk '{print $1" "$7}'
```

I can't really think of any other info I can give on this, so let me know if I am forgetting anything.

Comment: Btw, title sounds a bit scary to a non-tech person :-)

Comment: haha I never thought of it like that, maybe we need a tech mob.

Comment: it's for real, my mother walked into my room, glanced at the screen and asked me what kind of websites I visit :-)

Comment: No more mother heart attacks now, I changed the title =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [skill](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/skill.1.html) command instead:

```
skill -9 -u username
```

Comment: that works when I run it as root, but as apache, it does not work.  I also tried pkill since that was recommended when I looked up skill

Comment: I made this work by giving the apache user sudo access to skill with       apache  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/skill

Comment: I have same requirement, but I am doubtful about the security if I give access to apache. Please tell me is there any secure alternative for same, I thought of saving the process to be killed in a mysql table and executing a cron to kill them every minute. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Toby Joiner Can you make it more clear of, how can we give www-data user get access to run the skill command?

Comment: Ruhi, sorry I did not see your question forever ago.  @Sanjay Not sure what you are asking.  I did it in the sudoers file with the above addition.  I did it with the apache user, but I suppose you could do it with www-data the same way.