# How to kill a linux process using pid from php?

Tags: php, linux, apache, amazon-ec2

I am facing one issue regarding killing a Linux process from my php code.
I am running a Scrapy tool from my php code using the `proc_open()` function in the background.

It works fine, but now I want to kill this process using its process id.
To do that I'm using `exec("sudo kill -9 $pid");` where `$pid` is the process id which I'm getting from my php code.

The problem is this process is running on behalf of the apache user. I thought there might be some permissions issue, so I added apache user to the sudoers file like this `apache  ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD:ALL` but I'm still not able to kill it. Somehow, the same kill command works from my putty console.

My code is on an Amazon EC2 instance.

My question is, how can I kill that process identified by a pid from php?

Comment: BAD BAD idea - never grant apache sudo permissions!!!

Comment: Also, if `apache` is the owner of the process, did you try simply `kill -9 $pid`?

Comment: Thanks @SudiptaChatterjee.. Simply kill -9 $pid worked.. I had wasted so many days on this.. Thanks once again!

Comment: Simply, exec("kill -9 $pid"); worked..

Comment: Fantastic - please mark my answer below as correct :)

Comment: Also, never use kill -9 - it can mess up all sorts of things,  much better practice to use kill -15 and wait a little, and then only as a last resort, use kill -9.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Never, ever, give apache `sudo` permissions!

Use `exec("kill -9 $pid");` - your apache process started it, it can kill it :)

Comment: i couldn't do it with exec so i just needed to use shell_exec but anyway thanks it helped me a lot :)

Comment: Don't use `exec()` for this, use `posix_kill()` instead.  Also, it's bad practice to routinely use kill -9 as it forces the process to die instantly without cleanup (see other answer).  Instead, reserve kill -9 for when a process won't die. with kill -15 or kill -1 (SIGHUP).

Answer (score 10):

Try [`posix_kill`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-kill.php):

> ```
> bool posix_kill ( int $pid , int $sig )
> ```
>
> Send the signal sig to the process with the process identifier pid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exec with sudo privileges for skill that is more safer check out [kill users processes in linux with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308774/kill-users-processes-in-linux-with-php)

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: skill is obsolete? pkill is something you should look at.