# Pkill -f doesn't work for process killing

Tags: php, linux, kill-process, termination, pkill

I have this process running:

```
342 pts/2    T    0:00 sh -c sudo screen /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/btdownloadcurses "http://zoink.it/torrent/732A4A9B54B7E3A916C2835D936D985942F65A6D.torrent" --display_interval 20 --saveas "/srv/"
343 pts/2    T    0:00 sudo screen /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/btdownloadcurses http://zoink.it/torrent/732A4A9B54B7E3A916C2835D936D985942F65A6D.torrent --display_interval 20 --saveas /srv/
344 pts/2    T    0:00 screen /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/btdownloadcurses http://zoink.it/torrent/732A4A9B54B7E3A916C2835D936D985942F65A6D.torrent --display_interval 20 --saveas /srv/
```

I tried to run:

```
pkill -f http://zoink.it/torrent/732A4A9B54B7E3A916C2835D936D985942F65A6D.torrent
```

But the process still running.
How do I force kill the processes that contain: "http://zoink.it/torrent/732A4A9B54B7E3A916C2835D936D985942F65A6D.torrent" ?

---

**Question as edited below:**

```
ps ax | grep 'Momomoko.E01.140011.HDTV.H264.720p.mp4'
```

I want to kill all process that contain the above string.

I tried running the above line, and it returns three results:

```
  342 pts/2    T    0:00 sh -c sudo screen /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/btdownloadcurses "http://zoink.it/torrent/732A4A9B54B7E3A916C2835D936D985942F65A6D.torrent" --display_interval 20 --saveas "/srv/Momomoko.E01.140011.HDTV.H264.720p.mp4"
  343 pts/2    T    0:00 sudo screen /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/btdownloadcurses http://zoink.it/torrent/732A4A9B54B7E3A916C2835D936D985942F65A6D.torrent --display_interval 20 --saveas /srv/Momomoko.E01.140011.HDTV.H264.720p.mp4
  344 pts/2    T    0:00 screen /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/btdownloadcurses http://zoink.it/torrent/732A4A9B54B7E3A916C2835D936D985942F65A6D.torrent --display_interval 20 --saveas /srv/Momomoko.E01.140011.HDTV.H264.720p.mp4
```

How do I run this line:

```
ps ax | grep 'Momomoko.E01.140011.HDTV.H264.720p.mp4'
```

..with php, and `kill -9` all the matching processes?

Answer (score 34):

Try to use `kill` command rather

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

It will work for sure, cause I have tried it myself and very handy all times.

Use the following in a script file then run for loop with `kill` command,

```
ps|grep torrent|cut -f1 -d' '
```

like this for loop as shown below, as exact working copy from my system;

```
for p in `ps|grep torrent|cut -f1 -d' '`; do
   kill -9 $p
done
```

I hope this will help you finally.

As per latest edited question you want to run this with PHP, it can be implemented through `exec` command, please follow the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239840/how-to-kill-a-linux-process-using-pid-from-php/19240468) for solution.

Comment: @Limzhenxiang check again, I have updated answer as per your new requirement.

Comment: Had a similar problem (could not kill ruby process) when using pkill - using kill -9 worked perfectly -thanks!

Comment: @Skynet perhaps instead of ps|grep torrent| cut -f1 -d ;   use  pgrep -f torrent;

Comment: @mtnpaul that's also a good way, please post an answer for future readers.

Answer (score 12):

As you can see, the process are being run with screen command.

```
sh -c sudo screen /usr/bin/python
sudo screen /usr/bin/python
screen /usr/bin/python
```

Due to this you cannot `kill` the process with the command what you have used.

To kill the process, first search the `PID` process ID of the process and then use `kill` command with the PID. Like

```
$ kill -9 342
```

Also looking from your process list, it is visible that you have started the same process many times with different permission. So I suggest you kill all except one that is needed.

**EDIT :**
This single command would suffice:

```
$ ps ax | grep 'Momomoko.E01.140011.HDTV.H264.720p.mp4' | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}' | xargs sudo kill -9
```

Here is what it does :

> 1. ps ax : list the process
> 2. grep : grep for the requred process name
> 3. awk : to get only the PID's of the process from the grep ouput
> 4. xargs sudo kill -9 : xargs will pass one by one PID number to kill command

Comment: I don't see any major `EDITS` except for inclusion of `kill-process` tag

Answer (score 1):

If you have that zombie process open in a terminal, you can `Ctrl+z` it, which on most shells lets the process run in the background and outputs something like:

```
[1]  + 69880 suspended  someprocess
```

You can then actually kill it with:

```
kill -9 69880
```

the same id that was shown when suspended.