# Reload or restart python script in a bash shell

Tags: python, bash, shell

I'm a brand new noob in python universe, so don't judge me too fast :-)
I'm trying to force a python script to reload or restart at the beggining of a bash script.

I've tried :

```
pkill -f myscript.py
```

and

```
killall myscript.py
```

and others...

Actually, I would like to make run the same script that call .wav files after having changed those .wav files... If I don't reload the script or restart it, it keeps playing the old files.

Maybe, there is other solutions.
Here is the script I want to reload (it's a button script playing music for my daughter)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pygame
from gpiozero import LED, Button
from signal import pause

pygame.init()

button_sounds = {Button(2): pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples/1.wav"),
                 Button(3): pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples/2.wav"),
                 Button(4): pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples/3.wav"),
                 Button(17): pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples/4.wav")}

for button, sound in button_sounds.items():
    button.when_pressed = sound.play

pause()
```

And here is my bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash

***HERE THE COMMAND I NEED !***

rm -r /home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples/*
cp -r /home/pi/gpio-music-box/comptines/* /home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples/

/home/pi/gpio-music-box/music.py
```

Thank you very much, and scuze my english, I'm french :-)
Andy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pkill -f doesn't work for process killing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26902079/pkill-f-doesnt-work-for-process-killing)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#!/bin/bash

pid=$(ps auxwww | grep nameOfScript.py | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')

kill -9 $pid

rm -r /home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples/*
cp -r /home/pi/gpio-music-box/comptines/* /home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples/

nohup /home/pi/gpio-music-box/music.py &
```

Have a nice day

Comment: What it does : 

`ps auxwww` -> print the process

`grep nameOfScript.py` -> retrieve the lines we want

`grep -v grep` -> remove grep from the selection

`awk '{print $2}'` -> triming results to only show pid

Comment: Thank wagigi, 

despite your command line works, it doesn't stop the processes...

    pid=$(ps auxwww | grep nameOfScript.py | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
    
    echo $pid
    
    4343 4364 4389
    
    killall -9 4343 4364 4389
    
    >> No process found

Thx anyway !

Comment: You need to use `kill` and not `killall`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can reduce a lot of the "noise" from ps by using output formatting. You can then stop the need for using both grep and awk by using awk to do the searching also.

```
ps -eo "%p %a" | awk '/nameOfScript.py/ && $1 != PROCINFO["pid"] { print "kill -9 "$1 }'
```

This forces ps to only print the pid (%p) and the full command (%a). The output is then piped to awk where is searches for lines with the name of the script contained. It discounts any entries with the current process id of awk and then uses this to print a kill command with the relevant process id.

Once you have verified that the kill command displays as expected, you can use awk's system function to actually run the command through:

```
ps -eo "%p %a" | awk '/prometheous-things.py/ && $1 != PROCINFO["pid"] { system("kill -9 "$1) }'
```