# Excute cmd with php and kill the proccess

Tags: php, cmd, exec

I run a simple php code on windows machine:
exec('b.exe b.txt c.txt').

b.txt is the input and c.txt is the output.

sometimes the output txt file(c.txt) is very big and i need to prevent it by killing the process. I think i must check the size of output and if is bigger than 10 MB i must kill the exec.
Any idea about how i could kill the exec;

Comment: Why don't you check the filesize of `c.txt` and prevent execution if the file is too big?

Comment: the exec create the c.txt file but i need when that file is being bigger than 10 Mb to stop the execution

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1471320/4875631) to execute the command asynchronously. Use a while loop with a moderate sleep timer, and continually check the size of the `c.txt` file, and if the [process is still alive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3044045/4875631). Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19240468/4875631) to kill the process if it's too big.

Comment: could you give more details please